# Group notation in OEIS

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups, notation, oeis

I am wondering how I should interpret the notation that the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences ([OEIS)](https://oeis.org/) uses for finite groups.

An example is this sequence: [A008795](https://oeis.org/A008795)
In this specific case, what does the notation [2,n]+ = 22n mean?

Also, often these groups are mentioned because of their Molien series, that as far as I understand is the Hilbert series of the ring of invariants of a fixed representation. However, often the representation is not mentioned, so I guess these groups come with some natural representation of which the corresponding sequence is the Molien series. Is this correct?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you'll probably have luck at the SeqFan mailing list: http://list.seqfan.eu/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/seqfan.

Comment: The Wikipedia article section [on infinite families of axial sroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_groups_in_three_dimensions#The_seven_infinite_series_of_axial_groups) lists "Dihedral symmetry" as $22n$ or $[n,2]^+$ but clearly they depend on $n$.

Comment: This sort of helps. In the sense that still I do not understand why the n of the group changes (and if the n of the group determins the a_n of the sequence, then what are the representations, or the degrees that play some roles). I guess I will try to write on the mailing list suggested by @PeterKagey above